# mongodb serialize subset result

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have this simple db, with subset of elements:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5019eb2356d80cd005000000"),
    "photo" : "/pub/photos/file1.jpg",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "name" : "mike",
            "message" : "hello to all"
        },
        {
            "name" : "pedro",
            "message" : "hola a todos"
        }
    ]
},
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5019eb4756d80cd005000001"),
    "photo" : "/pub/photos/file2.jpg",
    "comments" : [
        {
            "name" : "luca",
            "message" : "ciao a tutti"
        },
        {
            "name" : "stef",
            "message" : "todos bien"
        },
        {
            "name" : "joice",
            "message" : "vamos a las playa"
        }
    ]
}
```

when I execute a subset find:
    db.photos.find({},{"comments.name":1})

Im receive this structure:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5019eb2356d80cd005000000"),
        "comments" : [
            {
                "name" : "mike"
            },
            {
                "name" : "pedro"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5019eb4756d80cd005000001"),
        "comments" : [
            {
                "name" : "luca"
            },
            {
                "name" : "stef"
            },
            {
                "name" : "joice"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I want to get a simple one-dimensional array, like this(or similar):

```
[
    {
        "name" : "mike"
    },
    {
        "name" : "pedro"
    },
    {
        "name" : "luca"
    },
    {
        "name" : "stef"
    },
    {
        "name" : "joice"
    }
]
```

I need to implement this query with mongo php official driver, but the language is not important, I just want to understand by what logic can I accomplish this by mongo shell

tnk!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option would be to use [distinct()](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct):

```
>db.photos.distinct("comments.name");
[ "mike", "pedro", "joice", "luca", "stef" ]
```

Here's another example using JavaScript:

```
// Array to save results
> var names = []

// Find comments and save names
> db.photos.find({},{"comments.name":1}).forEach(
          function(doc) { doc.comments.forEach(
              function(comment) {names.push(comment.name)})
          })

// Check the results
> names
[ "mike", "pedro", "luca", "stef", "joice" ]
```

Here's an example using the new aggregation framework in the upcoming MongoDB 2.2:

```
db.photos.aggregate(
  { $unwind : "$comments" },
  { $group : {
     _id: "names",
     names: { $addToSet : "$comments.name" }
  }},
  { $project : {
     '_id' : 0,
     'names' : 1,
  }}
)
```

Comment: thanks Stennie
I thought that there might be a simpler solution, but above that would be fine for several levels of depth of the document.
(this solution will require a foreach loop for each level of depth)

or I thought maybe I was wrong as I created my database design and maybe I should use

Comment: @StefanoCudini: added an example using the aggregation framework in MongoDB 2.2rc0.  Don't actually need the positional operator in this case .. just need to find and group the unique values.

Comment: Good solution! But I'm using mongodb over debian squeeze server and unfortunately I can not use a more recent version of 1.4.4
I am a neophyte mongodb and I think maybe I'm wrong in the project application, maybe I should use a separate collection for the comments and then put into an array of dbref "comments": [..]
this way I can retrieve a single query with all the comments on each document.

are not yet able to make the right choice, what solution you think is best?

or if the version 2.2 is growing fast and better to upgrade your version instead of following the debian repository?

Comment: @StefanoCudini: Having answered some more convoluted questions, I totally forgot the obvious choice, which was using `distinct()` :-p.  Updated example above.  As far as versions go, I would suggest using the latest [stable packages from 10gen](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian-or-ubuntu-linux/) which are currently MongoDB 2.0.6.

Comment: tnk!! I define this a perfect & elegant solution!! ;-)

Comment: I tried distinct() on version 1.4.4 returns an empty array!
Then updated to 2.0.6 and now is perfect!

Comment: @StefanoCudini: MongoDB 1.4.4 is *very* old (released June 30, 2010).  There have been significant improvements since then .. three major releases and 2.2 is almost out :).  Looks like the ability to use distinct() on arrays was added in the 1.6 prod release.